# AngularJS-UI-Router path before :params issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need, using `ui-routes`, to create multiple, compare-two-models pages with params like so:

```
http://localhost:3030/compare/thinkpad-t430-and-thinkpad-x220
```

Here is my `$stateProvider`:

```
.state('compareTwo', {
    url: '/compare/:models',
    templateUrl: '/views/compareTwo.html',
    controller: 'CompareTwoCtrl'
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<button type="submit" ui-sref="compareTwo({models: urlModelMain+'-and-'+urlModelCompare})" class="btn btn-primary">Compare</button>
```

Well its changes `url`, logs the message from the new controller, but still stays on the same view and controller.

But if you change `url: '/compare/:models'` to `url: '/:models'` everything works fine.

**Why is that?**

Comment: You probably have another state with the url `/compare` which is confusing it. If you extend a URL, the state should be `compare.compareTwo`

Comment: i have only `review`, `model`, `main` `compareTwo`

Comment: Please post all of your routes